# Flickering CSS and Javascript dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the HTML for my menu:

```
<div class="navLink four">
    <div>
        <a href="this.php">this</a>
        <div class="subMenu">
            <a href="link.php">link</a>
            <a href="link.php">link</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've got this jQuery to show and hide my menu:

```
$('.navLink div').hover(
  function () {
    $('.navLink div .subMenu').css({'display': 'none'});
    $(this).find('.subMenu:first').slideDown();
  },
  function () {
    $('.navLink div .subMenu').css({'display': 'block'});
    $(this).find('.subMenu:first').slideUp();
  }
);
```

And this CSS:

```
.navLink .subMenu {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}
.navLink > div:hover .subMenu {
    display: block;
}
```

But the dropdown flikers a lot when you hover over it, I think I need some preventDefault() or something in my javascript.

Comment: Nope, you just need to decide wether or not you're going to use CSS or javascript, and not use both. Right now the CSS hides and shows, and a split second later the javascript does the same, causing the flickering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a JSfiddle to show the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/V5H3A/

Here is the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/jdfqW/1/

You need to stop the animation like so:

```
$('.navLink div').hover(
    function () {
        $('.navLink div .subMenu').css({'display': 'none'});
        $(this).find('.subMenu:first').stop().slideDown();
    },
    function () {
        $('.navLink div .subMenu').css({'display': 'block'});
        $(this).find('.subMenu:first').stop().slideUp();
    }
);
```

For even less lines of code you can do this http://jsfiddle.net/jdfqW/2/:

CSS:

```
.navLink .subMenu {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$('.navLink div').hover(
    function () {
        $(this).find('.subMenu:first').stop().slideToggle();
    }
);
```

OR if you're SUPER adventurous **you can do it all with only CSS3** like so http://jsfiddle.net/jdfqW/3/:

CSS

```
.navLink .subMenu {
    height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transition:height 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition:height 0.5s ease;
    transition:height 0.5s ease
}

.navLink:hover .subMenu {
    height: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.navLink div a:first').mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).next('.subMenu').slideDown(200);
}).mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).next('.subMenu').slideUp(200);
});
```

Without any flickering `--->` http://jsfiddle.net/WK7We/

Answer (score 0):

**[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Yw4Ce/)**

Use `.stop()` method before `.slideUp()` and `.slideDown()`:

```
$('.navLink div').hover(
    function () {
        $('.navLink div .subMenu').css({'display': 'none'});
        $(this).find('.subMenu:first').stop().slideDown();
        // HERE --------------------- ^
    },
    function () {
        $('.navLink div .subMenu').css({'display': 'block'});
        $(this).find('.subMenu:first').stop().slideUp();
        // HERE --------------------- ^
    }
);
```

---

References:

- [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) - jQuery API Documentation

> Stop the currently-running animation on the matched elements.

Answer (score 0):

use `stop()`... this will stop the running animation which i assume is causing the flickering...

```
$(this).find('.subMenu:first').stop().slideDown();
$(this).find('.subMenu:first').stop().slideUp();
```